# Is there a way to simulate "ipfs add <some-string>" using javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, ipfs

I would like to simulate the ipfs command *ipfs add 'some string'* using the javascript *fetch* method on url '/http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add'

the documentation ( https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/ ) says that an argument *arg [file]* is needed. 
I tried using a file instead of a string this way :
*fetch(/http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add?arg=some.txt)* without any success.

A working example adding a file or a string to ipfs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code in the comment  at https://github.com/ipfs/http-api-docs/issues/4#issuecomment-391455691 seems relevant. https://js.ipfs.io/ also looks promising. https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs

Comment: The code at github.com/ipfs/http-api-docs/issues/4#issuecomment-391455691 is too much complicated as it uses formData. I would like a simpler example using fecth to add a simple string to ipfs.

Comment: To be more precise, the command lines :
echo "this is a string" > foo;
ipfs add foo ;
gives : 
added QmZ8X88cnVygpggEo11fqhSu6rYXA6eQBbtmq392EZbg92 foo
I want the same result using something like  fetch(/http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add?arg=foo)